# SQL Query to find price based on effective date only

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking to find a SQL query that will work to join a few tables, where the price column will show the price for a specific date.

The data I'm working wiht only gives me the effective date, so I need to be able to say for product purchased on date X, the price should be Y

Here are my two tables:

**Prices table:**

| Product | Price | Effective Date | Price code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | $ 2.00 | 1/1/2020 | W |
| 177 | $ 5.00 | 10/2/2021 | W |
| 123 | $ 2.50 | 10/7/2021 | W |
| 123 | $ 7.00 | 10/7/2021 | A |
| 500 | $10.00 | 12/1/2021 | W |
| 123 | $ 3.00 | 12/2/2021 | W |

**Purchases table:**

| Product | Purchase Date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 11/3/2021 |
| 123 | 12/7/2021 |

**The output I am hoping to get:**

| Product | Purchase Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 11/3/2021 | $2.50 |
| 123 | 12/7/2021 | $3.00 |

Here's the code I've tried so far that is not working:

```
  FROM [dbo.Purchases] a
  inner join [dbo].[Prices] b 
  on a.[Product] = b.[Product]
     Where [Price code] = 'W'
     and MAX(b.[Effective Date]) <= a.[Purchase Date]
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to edit a solution into the question. If you've found a solution you want to share, do so properly by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose - see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   distinct pr.Product
        ,[Purchase Date]
        ,first_value(pr.Price) over(partition by pu.Product, pu.[Purchase Date] order by [Effective Date] desc) as Price
from     Purchases pu join Prices pr on pr.Product = pu.Product and pr.[Effective Date] <= pu.[Purchase Date] and pr.[Price code] = 'w'
```

| Product | Purchase Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-11-03 00:00:00.000 | 2.5000 |
| 123 | 2021-12-07 00:00:00.000 | 3.0000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fkNRJY2U?hide=2)